# How to save the Mail merge PDF to a Document collection

Tags: email, pdf, merge

When performing a mail merge using document forms, the function `DocsList.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf")` converts the temporary document to PDF.

How can I save the PDF to a document collection immediately after sending the attached PDF via e-mail?